# Combine parts of SCO with parts of A2DP

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth, routes, a2dp

I'm looking to pair A2DP stereo sound with the interrupt functionality of `AudioManager`'s `MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION`. The purpose of this pairing is to insert snippets of custom music into AM/FM broadcasts by using the music as something that "dials" the Android device and stops the AM/FM broadcast.

I have this working decently with SCO using the following code to start the "phone call".

Here is the `AudioManager` code:

```
AudioManager localAudioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
localAudioManager.setMode(0);
localAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
localAudioManager.startBluetoothSco();
localAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
```

Here is the `MediaPlayer` I'm trying to play:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder()
    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
    .build());

mediaPlayer.setDataSource("https://wmbr.org/WMBR_Archive_128.m3u");
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

The audio produced by this code is low-quality and mono as opposed to stereo. I would like to change that.

The issue is that the [Android Dev site](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#startBluetoothSco()) for startBluetoothSco says:

> **Even if a SCO connection is established, the following restrictions apply on audio output streams so that they can be routed to SCO headset: - the stream type must be STREAM_VOICE_CALL - the format must be mono - the sampling must be 16kHz or 8kHz**

Is there any existing way to combine stereo sound and the interrupt functionality?

**Additional context**: in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432768/in-android-is-there-any-way-to-route-the-audio-to-a2dp-using-mode-in-communica) it seems that `MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION` and `MODE_IN_CALL` use the `PHONE` routing strategy. He also says

> If your BT accessory supports the Hands-free profile it will use a SCO link for the voice audio, and the ACL channel used for A2DP should be closed to avoid interference between the two.

I'm assuming this means my only option is a custom routing strategy, and I'm not sure what that entails.